# Programmatically delete S3 Glacier restoration

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is it possible to delete Glacier restoration before its expiry? In particular interested in doing it in Lambda (Python).

Comment: Are you looking for these [delete_archive](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glacier.html#Glacier.Client.delete_archive) and [delete_vault](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glacier.html#Glacier.Client.delete_vault) ?

Comment: amitd, no. I am talking about "When you use S3 Glacier or S3 Glacier Deep Archive, Amazon S3 restores a temporary copy of the object only for the specified duration. After that, it deletes the restored object copy." I wanted to know if it is possible to manually delete this copy before it expires and will be deleted by S3 Glacier.